# Как создать приложение на Android для контроля траты батареи другими приложениями?

Tags: java, android

есть задача разработать приложение, что будет отслеживать аномальные расходы батареи другими приложениями на Android и предлагать их отключить. Но поиск в гугле не дал информации о том, с помощью чего это можно сделать на Java.
И собственно вопрос - какие методы или библиотеки посоветуете использовать для этой задачи? Спасибо!